# Error : Can't serialize value : Expected a 'String' or 'java.time.temporal.TemporalAccessor' but was 'Timestamp'." in Spring Boot with Graphql

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql

I've devised an example of the usage of **Graphql** in **Spring Boot**.
I got an error related with the definition of **Date** when I wrote a query in **Graphiql**

Here is the error :  `Can't serialize value : Expected a 'String' or 'java.time.temporal.TemporalAccessor' but was 'Timestamp'."`

Here is my Doctor Entity which is shown below.

```
public class Doctor implements Serializable {
....
private Date birthday;
....
}
```

Here is my code snippet defined in **Graphiql** which is shown below.

```
{
  departments{
    id
    name
    doctors{
      id
      firstName
      lastName
      salary
      age
      birthday
    }
    hospital{
      id
      name
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my project file : [My Project Link](https://github.com/Rapter1990/springbootgraphql)

How can I fix it?

Comment: Will this solve your issue? https://github.com/donbeave/graphql-java-datetime
If not, could you, please, provide the steps to reproduce your issue?
I was able to start your spring boot application, but was unable to figure out what to do next.

Comment: @MykhailoSkliar I got this result. `"birthday": null`.  Where is the problem? How can I fix it?  Is it possible to write the answer step by step if you don't mind?

Comment: Don't use `Date`, it is old and obsolete; use `LocalDate` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following dependency to your pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.zhokhov.graphql</groupId>
  <artifactId>graphql-datetime-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

If it doesn't help, then take a look at this sample application:
https://github.com/donbeave/graphql-java-datetime/tree/master/graphql-datetime-sample-app

Try to write the test, similar to the test in this sample application, and try to experiment with different formattings and types, described in this article: https://github.com/donbeave/graphql-java-datetime

Answer (score 1):

Use `LocalDate` instead of `Date`, the `graphql-java-extended-scalars` library does not support a raw `Date` class but instead the new classes created from Java 8 to handle Dates and Times which all extend from `TemporalAccessor`

Anyway, you should not use Date unless you are working with legacy code